# how can I redirect blocks of text to different files based on a regex?

Tags: regex, sed, gawk

I have an output file (it's a `SQL DDL`, actually) where I'd like to write certain blocks to one file, and the rest to a second.
I was thinking either `gawk` or `sed` could do this.
Specifically, I'd like to redirect based on something like `/^CREATE (TABLE|VIEW)[^;]+/` to one file, and just dump the rest into a second.

Comment: `grep pattern` will give the lines containing the pattern as output, and `grep -v pattern` will give lines not containing pattern as output. Also both can be combined in a single `awk`

Comment: Ok, so I should amend: these statements are multi-line, hence the distinguishing semicolon.

Comment: Okk, Sadly I don't have any linux now, but the idea is, `awk` with `RS=;` (break the records based on `;`) Now `print $0 >> file` redirects the output to file, file can be a `awk` variable. Now `if($0 ~ pattern) file="myfile1"; else file="myfile2"` will switch the output depending whether the pattern is there or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -n -r -e '/CREATE (VIEW|TABLE)/,/;/ { w file1
              d
              }
              w file2' file.sql
```

This assumes that the semi-colon associated with the CREATE statements is not on the same line as the CREATE keyword.

#### file.sql

```
CREATE VIEW xyz AS
    SELECT * FROM SomeTable;

GRANT ALL ON xyz TO public;

CREATE TABLE pqr
(
    abc INTEGER NOT NULL,
    def VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON pqr TO public;

CREATE VIEW jkl AS
    SELECT * FROM pqr;
```

#### file1

```
CREATE VIEW xyz AS
    SELECT * FROM SomeTable;
CREATE TABLE pqr
(
    abc INTEGER NOT NULL,
    def VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
CREATE VIEW jkl AS
    SELECT * FROM pqr;
```

#### file2

```
GRANT ALL ON xyz TO public;


GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON pqr TO public;
```

Comment: That looks like it will work great!  I did get something similar to work using perl, which I resorted 'cause I needed capture groups.